# How to merge login and register form in one template on FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOSUserBundle in my Symfony application, 
I have the login and register forms in a separate template. I want both in one template to display them next to each other.

plz help me save my day !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>1</kbd> You need to have a first controller with a `loginAction` that renders a `login.html.twig` template. Let's assume this controller is `AcmeUserBundle:Security:login`.

<kbd>2</kbd> You need to have a second controller with a `registerAction` that renders a `register.html.twig` template. Let's assume this controller is `AcmeUserBundle:Registration:register`

<kbd>3</kbd> Create a third controller, for example `welcomeAction` that renders a `welcome.html.twig` template, and embed the controllers above on the same page.

```
{# AcmeUserBundle:Welcome:welcome.html.twig #}

{{ render(controller('AcmeUserBundle:Security:login'})) }}
{{ render(controller('AcmeUserBundle:Registration:register'})) }}
```

---

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#templating-embedding-controller) for more informations on how to embed controllers.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you for your help,just must be overriding the controller to handle errors.